# TF221122: An error occurred running job Test Management Warehouse Sync, ResultFailureTypeName (type IndexOutOfRangeException)

Tags: tfs

We have upgraded out TFS server 2012 update 2 to TFS 2012 Update 4. After update we found below error in event viewer. Now we cannot create new team project or cannot delete existing project. Now all the deleted project state showing as 'Deleted(Pending)'

```
TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:
Date (UTC): 4/6/2018 5:23:09 AM
Machine: TFS
Application Domain: TfsJobAgent.exe
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v4.0.30319
Service Host:
Process Details:
  Process Name: TFSJobAgent
  Process Id: 4660
  Thread Id: 4348
  Account name: DOMAIN\TFSService

Detailed Message: TF221122: An error occurred running job Test Management Warehouse Sync for team project collection or Team Foundation server Default Collection.
Exception Message: ResultFailureTypeName (type IndexOutOfRangeException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Warehouse.AdapterFormatHelper.FormatDimensionData(DimensionMember dm, Column col, SqlDataReader reader)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Warehouse.TeamTestWarehouseAdapter.CreateDimensionEntries(Mapping mapping, SqlDataReader reader)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Warehouse.TeamTestWarehouseAdapter.CallbackCreateFactAndDimensionEntries(Mapping mapping, SqlDataReader reader)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Warehouse.WarehouseResultDatabase.QueryTestResults(SqlBinary watermark, Int32 limit, ProcessRowCallback resetCallback, ProcessMappingDataCallback dataCallback)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Warehouse.TeamTestWarehouseAdapter.QueryForResults(WarehouseResultDatabase wrd, SqlBinary waterMark, Int32 limit)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Warehouse.TeamTestWarehouseAdapter.ProcessIntegratedResults(WarehouseRowVersionQueryDelegate wqd, String highWaterMarkProperty, String processLimitProperty, Int32 defaultLimit)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Warehouse.TeamTestWarehouseAdapter.MakeDataChanges()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseSyncJobExtension`1.MakeDataChanges(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, String& resultMessage)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseSyncJobExtension`1.RunInternal(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime queueTime, String& resultMessage)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseJobExtension.Run(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime queueTime, String& resultMessage)
```

Comment: Did you try to restart your server? When yo create or delete a team project, what error did you get?

Comment: Yes. i tried several times. this error recorded in windows event viewer when i tried again to delete the team project

Comment: Do you get any error on the team explorer when you create team project? Try to manually process the TFS data warehouse and analysis services cube by following this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/admin/manually-process-data-warehouse-and-cube?view=vsts&tabs=dim-work-item

Comment: This error has nothing to do with creating or deleting team projects. What error do you get when you attempt to create a Team Project?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - error when creating project
TF30170: The plugin Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.TestManagement failed during task TestSettings from group TestManagement.  
Explanation Plugin error text: “Soap Exception: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.ServiceVersionNotSupportedException: TF400860: The current version of the following service is not supported: TestManagement. Version: 10, MinVersion: 10. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: TF400860: The current version of the following service is not supported: TestManagement. Version: 10, MinVersion: 10. ---

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the cache files by following the steps below:

1. Clean the Cache folder on client computer. The folder path is: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache.
2. Clean the Cache folder on Server machine. The folder path is: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Web Access\Cache_v11.0
3. After cleaned, on Server machine, click Start and select Run… to open the dialog box, then input **iisreset.exe** and click OK, wait it run completely.

---

[image]

Comment: I've done the steps.. Still the same error when creating projects. On server there were no "Cache_v11.0" folder inside "Web Access".

Comment: Once we re-run shows below message,
--------------
You cannot re-run the selected servicing job for the team project collection.
---------------------------
OK   
--------------------------

Comment: How did you upgrade your TFS? Did it upgrade successfully?

Comment: Yes. it was upgrade successfully... anyway i think there is an issue with versions. we have planned to re-install everything from the beginning and upgrade to TFS 2013

Comment: Kindly share us your upgrade result.